# XML Namespace and schemalocation property?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

In many xml examples i see many nameschemas which even dont use in xml like in below example we have defined nameschemas as `xsi`, `aop` and one default 
namespace. If we dont use them what the purpose of defining them. Did not attach the xml as its quite big.

Second question is :- Assume that we using this nameschemas.. We usually defined the values of namechemas and `schemalocation` with some web address 
like `http://someAdddress//`. What if we define them with some arbitrary value like ABC or something else. Will it make any differnce? Is there any 
processing we do from these web addresses?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/ 
schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema 
/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">
```

Another question is we have defined the `schemalocation` for xsi namespace only Not for aop namespace. Why so?

Last question is can we define namespace `xsi1` instead of `xsi`? Does it make any im

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it should be the case that if a namespace binding isn't used within a document, a declaration of that namespace is redundant and can safely be omitted (conversely, it won't do any harm by being there.) I say it should be the case, but there are exceptions. One is DTD validation, which sometimes requires the presence or absence of a particular namespace declaration on a particular element (DTD processing isn't namespace aware, so it treats namespaces as attributes). Another rather rare exception: I have seen XML vocabularies where namespace declarations are used to convey semantics other than simply declaring a binding for a namespace prefix, for example it might indicate version information. That's bad XML design, but there's a lot of bad XML design about.

As for xsi:schemaLocation, some tools/applications will ignore this, others may interpret it as a request to perform schema validation against a schema found at a particular location.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. What about second question which  is :- Assume that we using this nameschemas.. We usually defined the values of namechemas and schemalocation with some web address like http://someAdddress//. What if we define them with some arbitrary value like ABC or something else. Will it make any differnce? Is there any processing we do from these web addresses?

Answer (score 0):

In your first paragraph you asked what if we define an XML namespace and don't use it?

Well nothing bad will happen. It's just there for your use and you don't use it. Its like a variable defined in your function that you just don't use.

Now there is an error in one of your statement that you do not use xsi, aop and default namespace. That is not true. Because xsi is xml schema instance. You use it in the next line where you write `<xsi:schemaLocation ... />` It basically lets you create an instance of the schema definition that you have created in your xsd/dtd file. You may/may not have used aop, I cannot tell until you show me the xml file. Now with default namespace, you are a little bit confused. Default namespace in XML documents tells the schema-validator that all the elements used in this XML document are declared in the "`<some namespace>`" namespace. See http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_schema.asp under the heading "Referencing a Schema in an XML Document".

Now your second question is that all the namespaces are generally defined as a url. Can we define it as some other name ?

Yes, you can. Here is a sample xsd and xml file.

```
<?xml
    version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8"
?>

<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="mynamespace"
    xmlns="mynamespace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
    <xs:element name="note">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="to">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required"></xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml
    version="1.0"
    encoding="utf-8"
?>

<note
    xmlns:note="mynamespace"
    xmlns="mynamespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="mynamespace myschema.xsd"
>
    <note:to lang="en"></note:to>
</note>
```

So you can see that I have defined another name for the namespace and it works perfectly in my eclipse.

I think (and I am guessing here) that there is a reason why people use URI as the namespace. Because if you simply keep a name like I did "mynamespace" and other people want to import/use your schema, then your name and their name might collide. Now you cannot write a simple name and hope that every person in the world will not use that name, so people use URI as their namespaces, because URI are unique and there is no reason for others to use your URI while creating schemas for their applications.

Your 3rd question was why have we not defined a schemaLocation for app just like we did for xsi?  Look again in your schemaLocation. You have defined 4 "space separated" values. 2 for xsi and two for aop.

Your last question was can you define xsi1 instead of xsi. You can. Infact you can define any name you want. Its a variable that is used as a shorthand to represent the namespace.

PS: I have started learning XML/XSD recently. So if you find my answer wrong, please share the correct answer and I will edit mine. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a XSD Schema to a XML file without using a namespace, you can also simply use the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute instead of `xsi:SchemaLocation`. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256139(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
<myElement
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="myschema.xsd"
>
```